# Watch function failing to capture change in data

Tags: angularjs

If you take a look at the file selectMe.js in this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/yf7Ywfj9RjDuaDnOx6DL?p=info

You will find a watch function as below:

```
scope.$watch(function() {
      return JSON.stringify(scope[attributes.selectMe]);
    }, function(_obj) {
      selected = (typeof _obj === 'undefined') ? false : JSON.parse(_obj);
      if (selected == true) {
        (selected.row === attributes.row && selected.col === attributes.col) ? element.addClass('highlight-me') : element.removeClass('highlight-me');
      }
    });
```

The watch is not executing the callback when there is a change in the data it's watching. 
What am I missing here ?

Answer (score -1):

What you are missing is `scope.$apply(function(){})`.

Have a look at http://plnkr.co/edit/z9vvZG66GFBs1KnneXlE?p=preview, which i believe is what you are expecting.

Comment: Selva.. scope.$appy does seem to work with the click event but doesn't seem to capture the keyup or keypress events.. any clues.. moreover i was wondering why i need to use scope.$apply().. in these cases